# req.cookies returns [Object: null prototype] {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httponly

I'm trying to implement authentication with jwt in nodejs where I send the accessToken in the response and the refreshToken a httpOnly and I have a route to help me "refresh the Token" .

this is the code for refreshing Token:

```
exports.refreshToken = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  console.log(cookies);
  if (!cookies?.jwt)
   return next(new AppError("you need to connect first", 401));
  const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;
  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ refreshToken }).exec();
  jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN, (err, decoded) => {
  if (err || foundUser.id !== decoded.id)
  return next(new AppError("who are you?", 403));
  const accessToken = jwt.sign(
  {
    id: decoded.id,
  },
  process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
  { expiresIn: "15d" }
);
  res.json({ accessToken });
});
});
```

so the problem is that I'm not recieving the cookie with the request so I can't "refresh" the current token and I have no idea why this is happening even though it was working just fine and I didn't change anything...

this is the app.js code where I set up everything

```
    const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const mongoSanitize = require("express-mongo-sanitize");
const cookieParser= require('cookie-parser');
const xss = require("xss-clean");
const userRouter = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const postRouter = require("./routes/postRoutes");
const commentRouter = require("./routes/commentRoutes.js");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const globalErrorHandler = require("./controllers/errorController");
process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
  console.log(err.name);
  console.log(err.message);
  console.log("shutting down...");
  process.exit(1);
});
const AppError = require("./utils/appError");
const hpp = require("hpp");


const port = 5000;
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true,
};


app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(mongoSanitize());
app.use(xss());
app.use(hpp());
app.use(cookieParser());

const limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 100,
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  message: "too many requests please try again in an hour",
});
app.use(helmet());
app.use("", limiter);

const URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
mongoose
  .connect(URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("connected!"));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App running on port ${port}`));

app.use('/users',userRouter);

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
  next(new AppError(`can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server`, 404));
});

app.use(globalErrorHandler);
```

Edit:

this is the login function where I send the cookies:

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password").exec();
  if (!user || !user.correctPassword(password, user.password)) {
    return next(new AppError("Credentials are wrong", 404));
  }
  const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN, {
    expiresIn: "15d",
  });
  const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
    { name: user.name },
    process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
    {
      expiresIn: "60d",
    }
  );
  user.refreshToken = refreshToken;
  await user.save();
  user.refreshToken = undefined;
  res.cookie("jwt", refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "None",
    secure: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
  });
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    accessToken,
    data: { user },
  });
});
```

Comment: could it be because you are not sending the cookie in your requests? Do note you will not be able to capture the cookie value in Javascript at frontend.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I don't need to send it from the front cause it's a httpOnly cookie right? once you send it from the server it gets in the request and you can access it with req.cookies it was working fine before but somehow it stopped working

Comment: Well, can u show your front end `fetch` part? for example `credentials: "same-origin"` settings is needed for fetch requests.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I'm using axios in the frontend and i'm setting withCredentials property to true, alsoI've tried the endpoint using postman and it didn't work also.